# define val variable visible on catch

Tags: scala

Silly question I´m learning scala, and I found that since I´m using inmutable val I cannot define a val out of the try/catch to be visible in the catch. So in this case, what is the normal behave??

This is my code

```
  try {
    val jsonAlbum=  new JSONObject(json.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])
    val album = AlbumFactory.create(jsonAlbum)
    albums = albums ++ List(album)
  } catch {
    case e: NoSuchElementException => {
      println(s" Excewption adding alnum:$jsonAlbum")--> This val is not visible
  }
```

jsonAlbum is not visible in the catch since is not defined out of the try

Obviously I would like to keep it val and not var

Comment: As is you can do it with `lazy val jsonAlbum = ???; try { useJsonAlbumEvaledOnlyThere } catch { case e: Throwable => ??? }`

Comment: it looks not functional also what happens if you define jsonAlbum at outer scope and then it throwed exception during creation JsonObject ? Mostly you shouldn't need that in catch block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can `val jsonAlbum=  new JSONObject(json.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]])` throw `NoSuchElementException`? If not, just declare `jsonAlbum` before that try/catch block. If yes, you wouldn't see correct value of `jsonAlbum` in catch block anyway, because it's creation failed.

Note that you can use something like

```
val a = try { ... } catch { ... }
```

if you want to keep visibility without code garbage.

Comment: Silly  me, you right new JSONObject was not the point where the exception might be thrown

Answer (score 1):

The `val`s and `var`s inside the `try` block are not visible in the `catch` block. Its same with java as well.

If the data members have to be visible then they should be declared above try block. Note that You cannot reinitialise if its a val.

```
var x: A = null

try {
  x = someThingBad()
} catch {
 case ex => println(s"""$x""")
}
```

Comment: I knew that, but it's rubish, the language should be prepare for this